# Closing a pipe between programs without blocking

Tags: c++, linux

I have two programs that I am using to test passing messages between using pipes on an embedded linux device.  Below is an example of what I am running:

Receiver.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << "Starting Receiver" << std::endl;
  int receiver = open("/dev/rtp10", O_RDONLY);
  if (receiver < 0){
    perror("Open Receiver failed");
  }
  //...
  close(receiver);
  std::cout << "Ending Receiver" << std::endl;
}
```

Sender.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  std::cout << "Starting Sender" << std::endl;
  int sender = open("/dev/rtp10", O_WRONLY);
  if (sender < 0){
    perror("Open Sender failed");
  }
  //...
  close(sender);
  std::cout << "Ending Sender" << std::endl;
}
```

When I run these programs, they successfully open, do that is in the `//...` section, and move to close.  However, what happens at that point is that 1 of the programs successfully closes, and the other hangs on close.  What I would like to do is have a way to close the pipes successfully such that both programs can close properly.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the // part

Comment: Considering that the code functions in the same manner when I reduce the `//...` statements to nothing more than `std::cout << message` statements, I rather doubt that is the problem.

Comment: What is `/dev/rtp10`? Which one of these programs hangs? How do you know it hangs in `close`?

Comment: `/dev/rtp10` is the name of a pipe that is built in with the version of embedded linux I am using.  As for how I know it hangs at close, part of what is in the `//...` section is that right before `close()` is called, I have a line `std::cout << "closing pipe" << std::endl` and the programs execute up until that line - one goes past, and the other stalls there.  Lastly, it is not consistent in which program hangs.  Sometimes it is the reader, other times the writer.

Comment: Does it work if you give it a named pipe created with `mkfifo` instead of what looks like a device driver acting as a named pipe?

Comment: @Harvey And it works when I use mkfifo.  So it appears that the problem is with the `/dev/rtp*`.  It appears that I will have to worry about working with that once I get to using the embedded device's own libraries, and I have example code that works there.  But for testing linux to linux talking, I need the mkfifo first.